# Multi Tenancy in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I have the following scenario:
At first I need an application (ASP.NET MVC) with different tenants based on the user login. This step is easy to implement and not need to be answered. Let's say the application is deployed as myapp.com.

On top of the Application a "super-admin" or host should be able to create new tenants for the application.
At runtime the super-admin should be able to set a new application like tenant1.myapp.com. In the backend a new database should be created for the tenant. 
My target is to build an application one time and for each new customer just create a new tenant like tenant1.myapp.com with a specific database and let them use it.

How could i implement this? Is it possible to create a new database with Entity Framework and run migrations programmatically?

I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Please share with us about your trials so far with this use-case.